# PHP from the command line don't give correct result

Tags: php

I use Windows 11.
When I execute a PHP file in Windows PowerShell, I don't have the result attendee.

For example:

```
<?php
fscanf(STDIN,"%d",$x);
$tab=array();
for ($i=0;$i<$x;$i++){
    $row = stream_get_line(STDIN,6+1,"\n");
    $tab[] = $row.(strrev($row));
}
echo("\n");
foreach ($tab as $x){
echo($x."\n");
}
foreach (array_reverse($tab) as $x){
    echo($x."\n");
}
```

the result is

```
PS C:\wamp64\www\> php tablereverse.php
2
ab
bb

ba
bb
bb
ba
```

but if I run the file with PHPStorm the result is

```
C:\wamp64\bin\php\php8.1.13\php.exe C:\wamp64\www\tableReverse.php
2
ab
bb

abba
bbbb
bbbb
abba
```

I use the same PHP path

```
PS C:\wamp64\www\> php -v
PHP 8.1.13 (cli) (built: Nov 22 2022 15:49:14) (ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.13, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.13, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your PhpStorm output. What exact tool within the IDE are you using? Are all lines the same colour or some of them are red?

Comment: I used the run functionality . shortcut "MAJ+F10"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For historial reasons, we have two characters involved in new lines, that originally represented two different actions that could be performed by [teletype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleprinter) carriage (the sliding printing head):

- Carriage return (represented as `CR` or `\r` depending on the language) would move carriage to the first column (horizontal movement).
- Line feed (`LF` or `\n`) would move carriage to next row (vertical movement)

Operating systems adopted different conventions to represent a new line:

- Unix chose `\n`
- Microsoft chose `\r\n`
- Apple chose `\r` (and eventually switched to `\n` much later).

You're setting `\n` as separator:

```
stream_get_line(STDIN,6+1,"\n");
```

But Windows programs typically use `\r\n`. That means that the string you're reversing contains a trailing `\r` character and, depending on the software used to *display* it, you may see different outcomes:

- An actual carriage return
- A hidden character
- Cursor moves to start of line

What happens here is that PowerShell, Command Prompt (aka CMD) and a PhpStorm terminal panel running either, will literally render that `\r` inside `ab\rba` as carriage return, so after printing the first two letters, cursor moves back and the next letters overwrite what was already printed in that line. On the other side, PhpStorm's "Run" feature implements its own terminal emulator and its behaviour is the hidden character.

This is better spotted if you add some debugging information and unique input strings:

[image]
[image]

A possible solution is to switch to [fgets()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php), which understands all styles, and strip the newline yourself:

```
$row = rtrim(fgets(STDIN, 6 + 1));
```

Comment: I replaced "\n" by PHP_EOL. It works fine now. Thanks.

Comment: I've edited my answer because, even though the root cause was identified correctly, the rest of my diagnostic was pretty much wrong.